# UPCapture a part of a window

Tags: video, window-manager

I'm running Arch Linux. I want to make a video. I want to record a part of a window. I want to record my window even if there is some other window on top of it (the top window should not appear in the recording).

I think that this should be possible using some compositing WM.

UPD: It seems that something like this is real: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=117275. I didn't manage to reproduce such thing, though.